# Getting taxonomy images to display on single-post with their terms

Tags: plugins, php, custom-taxonomy, images, terms

Having some trouble with [taxonomy images plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-images/).

I am on single-post.php and I want to display my post's taxonomy terms & the term's associated images. Ideally, I'd like the taxonomy description there too. No idea why this has me stumped because it seems like it should be a simple thing to do.

I have this code, which displays just the post's term's images:

```
$terms = apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-list-the-terms', '', array(
            'taxonomy' => 'comedians',
        ) );

        foreach( (array) $terms as $term){
            echo $term;
        }
```

I also have this, which displays the post's terms:

```
        print get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'comedians', '<li>', ',</li><li>', '</li>' );
```

And then I have this code, which displays all of the term's images, with the terms & links & descriptions:

```
$terms = apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-get-terms', '', array(
            'taxonomy' => 'comedians',
        ) );
        if ( ! empty( $terms ) ) {
            print "\n" . '<div class="row">';
            foreach( (array) $terms as $term ) {
                print "\n" . '<div class="four columns">';
                print "\n\t" . '<a href="' . wp_get_attachment_url( $term->image_id ) . '" rel="lightbox unique-woo-feature">' . wp_get_attachment_image( $term->image_id, 'unique-woo-feature' ) . '</a>';
                print "\n\t" . '<h5>' . esc_html( $term->name ) . '</h5>';
                print "\n\t" . '<p>' . esc_html( $term->description ) . '</p>';
                print "\n" . '</div>';
            }
            print "\n" . '</div>';
        }
```

What I need is something in between. I understand the crucial part is the filter, specifically the difference between `get-terms` and `list-the-terms` but the latter one, which gets the post's terms like I need, doesn't seem to do anything but just the images no matter what I do.

Any help with this, much appreciated.

Comment: Have the same problem, how can you develop a plugin and leave out the most basic use case is beyond my comprehension.

Answer (score 3):

I was having trouble with this too.  Wanted to show all the term images on a single post page. I found that you need to loop through the terms first (in my case, taxonomy=st_colors), then loop through the images associated with those terms. Here is how I solved it:

```
    <?php
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'st_colors' );
foreach ($terms as $term) : 

    $colors = apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-get-terms', '', array(
        'taxonomy' => 'st_colors',
            'term_args' => array(
                'slug' => $term->slug,
                )
        ) 
    );
    foreach( (array) $colors as $color) :
        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $color->image_id, 'full', array('class' => 'alignnone'));
        echo $term->name;
    endforeach;

endforeach;
?>
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score -2):

if you are not using a plugin  use this function

```
z_taxonomy_image_url($term_id, 'thumbnail', TRUE)
```

Comment: Where is that function coming from, can you please explain?

Comment: Good new answers are always appreciated, but `z_taxonomy_image_url()` is not a WordPress function. It seems to come from [https://wordpress.org/plugins/categories-images/](https://wordpress.org/plugins/categories-images/), which is not part of the OP's question.